# How to visualize Kubernetes diagram

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there a tool or command that would draw Kubernetes pod topology?
I would like to illustrate the relations between pods so that I can visualize the high-level architecture diagram of an existing cluster.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [graph plugin](https://github.com/steveteuber/kubectl-graph) with kubectl or [Weave Scope](https://www.weave.works/docs/scope/latest/introducing/) and [Lens](https://k8slens.dev/) which have GUI